# apply function on subset of dataframe rows in column based on value in other column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

New to pandas, so please bear with me.

I have a text processing function I'd like to run on a column in my datafame conditional on the value in another column. I've seen

Depending on whether something is flagged, I want to run a translation function on it.

```
   account  article    ... translation  flag
0    123      text      ...               1
1    123      text      ...               0
2    123      text      ...               1
```

I tried:

`df['translation'] = df[['flag', 'text']].apply(lambda x: translate(['article']) if ['flag'] == 1 else None)`

and get this in return:

```
ValueError: ('The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().', 'occurred at index flag')
```

Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I used a test DataFrame similar to yours, without *translation* column:

```
   account article  flag
0      123   text1     1
1      123   text2     0
2      123   text3     1
```

Then I defined a "surrogate" translation function:

```
def translate(txt):
    return '_' + txt + '_'
```

And to call it conditionally, run:

```
df['translation'] = df.apply(lambda row:
    translate(row.article) if row.flag == 1 else None, axis=1)
```

The result is:

```
   account article  flag translation
0      123   text1     1     _text1_
1      123   text2     0        None
2      123   text3     1     _text3_
```

**What was wrong in your code:**

1. In you want to limit source data to a subset of columns, use **existing**
   column names (*article* instead *text*) and include all columns used
   in the applied function.
2. The lambda function is applied to each **row**, so you should have passed
   *axis=1* parameter (default *axis* is **0**).
3. When your function is called, the current **row** is passed as a parameter
   (*x*), but to refer to some column in it you should have used *x.column_name*
   notation. E.g. my solution could also be:

   ```
    df[['article', 'flag']].apply(lambda row:
        translate(row.article) if row.flag == 1 else None, axis=1)
   ```
4. Argument like *['article']* is here just a **list**, containing one
   word (*article*). I doubt whether your translation function is able to
   process a **list** argument.
5. A similar remark concerning *if ['flag'] ...*. This is **not** a reference
   to a column in the source row.

Comment: This worked! And thank you for the explanation. I wrote my sudo code too quickly, sorry. Points 1,4, and 5 are more oversight than anything. Is the lambda, axis issue above related to lambda, or pandas?

Comment: *Axis* parameter is related to *apply*. It decides what is passed to the applied function (a row (*axis=1*) or a column (*axis=0*)).

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you may try `map` and `where`

```
df['translation'] = df['article'].map(translate).where(df['flag'].eq(1), None)
```

Comment: And what if we already have some previous values in the column that we what to populate (which is `translate` in tis example)?  That is, what if we want to apply the function only to some rows while leavening the other rows intact?  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

you could use the `.loc` method. The advantage is that the code is more readable:

```
df.loc[df['flag'] == 1, 'translation'] = df['article'].apply(translate)
```

First you define the rows of interest using a conditional statement (`df['flag'] == 1`) and second to column to which the new values should be assigned to (`'translation'`)

**Edit**:

this results in the same output:

```
  article  flag  account translation
0   text1     1      123     _text1_
1   text2     0      123         NaN
2   text3     1      123     _text3_
```

If you need to remaining rows to be `None`, than initialize the the column with `None`:

```
df['translation'] = None
df.loc[df['flag'] == 1, 'translation'] = df['article'].apply(translate)
```

If you want to execute `translate` only on the flagged rows, than you can use `.log` twice:

```
df.loc[df['flag'] == 1, 'translation'] = df.loc[df['flag'] == 1,'article'].apply(translate)
```

Source:
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html